# What could be convenient way to implement filter external for Angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

At the [source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/6404a970c48f10e496010f1996004abae23ba0fd/src/js/core/factories/GridApi.js) at line 50 it says:

```
/**
           * @ngdoc event
           * @name filterChanged
           * @eventOf  ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi
           * @description  is raised after the filter is changed.  The nature
           * of the watch expression doesn't allow notification of what changed,
           * so the receiver of this event will need to re-extract the filter 
           * conditions from the columns.
           * 
           */
          this.registerEvent( 'core', 'filterChanged' );
```

In my case, I have `people table` having three columns which are `Name`, `Surname` and `Email`. I could handle filterChanged:

```
vm1.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
....
}
```

send all my parameters server side and search in all fields.

This may work for few columns. [See plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh7qlydGf7SLaB39LZWP?p=preview)

For huge table what could it be convenient way handle in client side?

with the help of @PaulL's answer, I reached *this solution:*

```
vm.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
    var grid = vm.gridApi.grid;
    var filters = [];
    vm.gridApi.grid.columns.forEach(function (column) {
        if (column.filters && column.filters[0].term) {
            filters[column.name] = column.filters[0].term;
        };
    });
    console.log(filters);
    service.getEntries(filters, paginationOptions.pageNumber, paginationOptions.pageSize, paginationOptions.sortDir).
    then(function (result) {
        vm.gridOptions.data = result.data.value;
    })
});
```

Comment: I'd still be tempted to look at a debounce - if someone types "male" into a filter, you're at risk of calling the server for "m", then "ma", then "mal", then "male".  That's load that you don't need.  If you put in a `var cancel = $timeout(function() { service.getEntries...;},500);` then you can cancel and restart the timer on each keypress.  User experience only suffers by 500ms.

Comment: @PaulL I'll do it, I am a bit lazy now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I'd just extract them using:

```
var filters = [];
$scope.gridApi.grid.columns.forEach( function(column) {
  if( column.filters && column.filters.length > 0 ) {
    filters.push({name: column.name, filters: column.filters});
  };
});
```

You can then process those filters as appropriate before sending to the server.  I would also usually debounce the filter, you don't want to call the server with every keypress.